# Where do I insert the custom.css file in the HTML when using CKEditor 5?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, ckeditor5

[According to the documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html#customization-with-css-variables), CKEditor 5's theme styling can be customised by making a `custom.css` file and "*referenced directly in HTML **after the `<link>` tag** injected by the editor and its content will simply override the default CSS variables.*"

In my application there is no `<link>` tag injected by the editor. There is only a `<style>` tag inserted as the last element in the `<head>` tag like such:

```
<style data-cke="true">.ck.ck-placeholder:before ...</style>
```

So where exactly does the `custom.css` file go so I can style the CKEditor's toolbar myself?